# Creating tables with SQL (PostgreSQL 13.1) from ER diagram

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-relationship

I am trying to set up the tables according to the diagram, and had no trouble creating the *team* table. However I'm not able to create the foreign key reference in the *match* table (one match contains two references to two distinct teams).
When I run the code for setting up the match table I get this error:

```
psql:tables.sql:13: ERROR:  number of referencing and referenced columns for foreign key disagree
```

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong in the code, comments on the ER diagram (am I doing something wrong there), or if there is something I'm misunderstanding in the table setup. Thnx in advance for any answers!

[image: ER diagram]

```
CREATE TABLE team (
    id CHAR(3) NOT NULL, 
    team_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    stadium VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    coach VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id, stadium)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE match (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    match_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, 
    stadium VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    home_team_id CHAR(3) NOT NULL, 
    away_team_id CHAR(3) NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (home_team_id)
        REFERENCES team(id, stadium), 
    FOREIGN KEY (away_team_id)
        REFERENCES team(id, stadium)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE goal (
    FOREIGN KEY (match_id) REFERENCES match(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team(id), 
    player VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    time_played INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (time_played, match_id)
);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use `char`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29_even_for_fixed-length_identifiers)

Comment: Your table `goal` has not column `match_id` or `team_id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used `char` because they use `varchar` for team(id) in [this](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation) example, but I wanted to have a fixed length id. Don't know why `char` shouldn't be used though.

Comment: read the link from my comment. `char` has absolutely no advantage over `varchar` but has several annoying disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Your DDL does not match the ERD.  The ERD does not have `stadium` in `team`.

The reference for an FK must be a PK in the referenced table.

Something like this should work:

```
create table team (
  id char(3) not null primary key,
  team_name varchar(30) not null unique,
  coach varchar(30) not null
);

create table match (
  id serial primary key,
  match_date date default current_date,
  stadium varchar(30) not null,
  home_team char(3) not null references team(id),
  away_team char(3) not null references team(id)
);

create table goal (
  match_id int not null references match(id),
  team_id char(3) not null references team(id),
  player varchar(30) not null,
  time_played integer not null,
  primary key (match_id, time_played)
);
```

[Fiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0ad41bb3fb07d0cf09596c3148295dc1)